# comparing 2 arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, compare, difference

I am trying to compare two different arrays and get the values that do not exist in 1 of the arrays. Here are my 2 arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => 2fbd5868-28ec-418d-854a-0736db720c8a [1] => f4a41974-5373-4862-a5e7-9d28b8c2301f [2] => a1874f68-3da1-47c3-97ef-a68580ce2a52)

Array ( [0] => 2fbd5868-28ec-418d-854a-0736db720c8a [1] => f4a41974-5373-4862-a5e7-9d28b8c2301f [2] => a1874f68-3da1-47c3-97ef-a68580ce2a52 [3] => 583cee91-1913-4e9d-b51d-e27083420001)
```

As you can see the second array has an additional value. I am trying to user array_diff like this:

```
$result = array_diff($array1,$array2);
print_r($result);
```

However the out of the array_diff is:

```
array()
```

Any ideas what is going on?

As people have suggested and i have already tested switching the arrays around, this is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => )
```

Comment: first read, then use..http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: try `array_diff($array2,$array1);`, this will work..

Comment: @Coderanonymous i then get this output: Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: @danyo What is the **exact** output which you get when you do: `var_dump($array1); var_dump($array2);` ?

Comment: Could you paste the code from initializing the arrays to printing the diff?

Comment: @axxis that is my code above

Comment: I don't see the code that initializes the arrays. Is there also any code between the initialization and the diff?

Comment: Why are my comments ignored? Should I bet, that you have some whitespaces in your values, so they don't match and you just have to try: `$result = array_diff(array_map("trim", $array2), array_map("trim", $array1));`

Comment: Could you also var_dump $array1 and $array2 just before calling array_diff?

Answer (score 2):

`array_diff` gives you the values from `$array1` that are not in the other arrays. All the values of your first array are in the second. Sou change the order of your arrays and you should be fine.

See also here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-diff.php

Comment: agree with @bish, or you can check the lengths then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in `array_diff()` is important

> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not
>   present in any of the other arrays2

Read [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array_diff($array2,$array1);
```

Try like this

Comment: i then get this output: Array ( [0] => [1] => )